# Is there a reliable way to repair a pin hole leak in a radiator

Tags: radiator, leak

I have heard a few different ways to fix a pin hole leak in a radiator. I have heard put a small amount of black pepper in the radiator, or use jb weld to patch the hole, and not to use the stop leak antifreeze.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to drain the coolant, most radiators can be brazed or welded to fix pinholes.

Comment: does this include aluminum radiators?

Comment: Aluminum radiators can be welded by someone who knows what's they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't really care if I might hurt the car, I might be willing to try JB Weld...

Comment: Seconded. At worst you'll ruin an already-dead radiator, not any other part of the car. I've had luck with this method in the past, although it was a giant gaping hole and I added some radiator stop-leak too after using the JB weld.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed radiators in the past, but unless your car is one where the replacement radiator is really expensive, you're probably better off just replacing it. A new radiator will usually give **much** better cooling performance. Last time I replaced a radiator is was just $70 or so...

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago, I brazed my non-aluminum, non-plastic radiator pin hole shut with a metal coat hanger and disposable propane hand torch. Never had a problem again with that radiator and it lasted for many years.

Otherwise, scrubbing with acetone and using JB Weld "Extreme Heat" and a piece of metal flashing might be worth a try (follow safety procedures).